# Start different activity from GCM if app is not running

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've correctly implemented server side and client side GCM handling extending GCMBaseIntentService...

My problem lies here, I have just two activities in my app, a splashscreen (which logs a user in on a server among other things) and the mainactivity with various fragments...

I'd like for a notification to be able to know if the app is running when the PendingIntent is launched...Because if the app is running I could just call the mainactivity and handle the request there, but if the app is not running I need to go through my splash activity first...

I'm able to see if the app is running when the GCM message arrives through a static boolean in my mainactivity, but what if the user or the system kills the app? My PendingIntent would still point to my main activity as that was running when the message arrived...

Right now I have a backup plan of just merging the splash and the mainactivity so I can always send the intent to my mainactivity, but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner solution, thanks!

Comment: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: Interesting stuff, though I just called it splash it isn't a brand or logo or anything...It downloads stuff from the server and logs in the user...I can't remove this step...